# Pulling in 2 million records monthly and deciding to update or duplicate

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I will be pulling nearly 2 million records monthly in the form of a CSV from a government website.  From there, it will be put into a postgres DB.  The trade-off needs to be discussed because in reality, only a few thousands records will be NEW or updated from the month prior.  The rest will remain static, so you can imagine the sheer amount of duplicates that will be persisting monthly.  Also, I'll be adding a foreign key to said table, so that's another thing to consider.  The foreign key issue is why I want to update rather than duplicate, but I am having some performance issues.

Can someone guide me a little bit?

Thanks!

Comment: 2 million per month is not very many.  What performance issue are you having?

Comment: 1. How are you versioning/updating the data? 2. Does the source data contain any metadata that might indicate the data has been updated?

Comment: I'm having a tough time mass importing via a Ruby on Rails gem while updating duplicates.  I'm sure the select statement that's been abstracted is not the most efficient way of doing things but the library is well-maintained and has a great reputation.  Either way, I'm getting a memory allocation error..  I'm more fishing for "it's okay to have duplicates" but that seems lazy.  And yes, I have a date parameter that can distinguish between replacing a duplicate or updating said duplicate ID.

Comment: Basically, I think the update duplicate built-in method is what's causing memory issues.  I can post code later.

Comment: When you say you have a foreign key, do you mean a key from your table refering to some other table ? Or do you have other tables referring to this table ?

Comment: As already said 2 million rows is very small. You say that you get those records in one step once a month ? My approach would be to drop or truncate the table and bulk load the new records. That should take just a few minutes. Then re-enable your foreign key, which should be another few minutes.

Comment: You also need to clarify what you mean by “performance issues”. How long does it take? How long would you like it to take ? That process runs once a month in batch mode, so it does not look like something time-critical, as long as it completes within the window allotted to daily batch processes.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Well, Ruby's active record times out after about 45 minutes with this error - ````ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::OutOfMemory: ERROR:  out of memory DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 4194304 in memory context "ErrorContext".
):````.  When I say a foreign key, I mean it has a ````user_id```` with a ````belongs_to```` relationship between a user table.  Look at this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534237/using-activerecord-import-to-mass-import-csv-data-and-update-duplicates-statem?noredirect=1#comment122906967_69534237  There's no raw ```sql```

Comment: If it's a matter of just adding all the records and assigning the foreign key to the latest record based off of ID, I can do that.  I am new to DB work, so it worried me to think about maintaining relational integrity through importing duplicates monthly

Comment: I said Ruby's - meant Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I think we need to see the table definition and the description of the CSV file. As for the foreign key: how is this user_id column populated ? Is it in the source CSV file ?